# How to stack an overlay over html5 video

Tags: css, html

I have attempted the answers found here but still cannot fathom how to overlay a images and text over html5 video. Whatever I try the elements simply stack above or below one another. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrap_video">
    <div id="video_box">
      <div id="video_overlays">
         <img src="img/overlay.png"</img>
         <a> TEXT </a>
      </div>         
    <div>
     <video id="player" src="mov/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop>">Your browser does not support this streaming content.</video>
  </div>   
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0px;
}
#video_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
}
#video_overlays {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  z-index: 100;
}
video#player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  z-index: 99;
}
#wrap_video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
}
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Yes, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/bnzfY/

Comment: try adding a background color. Then you will see that they are in fact over the video

Comment: As to what @Johansrk said, add a background color the style for `#video_overlays` and you'll see that it does actually cover the video.

Comment: @Fizz , I hate to admit it, but you are quite correct. Guess what was missing… linking the style sheet in the first place. Ugh. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <div id="wrap_video">             
<video id="player" width="960px" height="720px" loop="loop">
    <source src="mov/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support this streaming content.
</video>
     <div id="video_overlays">
          <img src="http://images.apple.com/v/ios/carplay/a/images/carplay_icon.png"/>
         <a href="#"> TEXT </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
margin: 0px;
}
#wrap_video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#video_overlays {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 720px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}
#player{
    background: purple;
}
```